# Why are the two ways of deleting a point in a shapefile different

Tags: qgis, shapefile

There are two ways of deleting an object in a shapefile (QGIS).

- Method 1
  Select visually the object on the map and click delete. The visual object is deleted, but its data in the attribute table are kept.
- Method 2
  Open the attribute table select the object line and delete. Both attribute table data and object on the map are deleted

What is the reason of these different behaviours?

Comment: Both should delete the point and attributes. Have you pressed "Reload the table" button?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean by 'reload the table'. WHat i did is delete visually the object, save and close QGis. Re open QGis and the table still contains the deleted object (with virtual fields at NULL.

Comment: I do not see any icon "reload the table", but see 2 buttons that I can translate  as "Update all lines" and "Update selected lines" (I use the french version). I tsted the 2 buttons and I got an error saying "Error calculating virtual field, no root available"

Comment: I use version 3.16.16, French langage

Comment: I just tried with a shapefile using QGIS 3.24 and can not reproduce. Deleting the selected point in the map or deleting the selected record in the attribute table immediately deletes both point and attribute table record.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wil envisage upgrading, but can just see the new annoucement release of 3.22.

Comment: after deleting it is necessary to save and close the editing, moreover, it is necessary to close the attribute table and reopen it.

Comment: I encountered in older versions, this is reload button on attribute table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUMXK.png